# If file from subdirectory is in list then copy to destination

Tags: python

Beginner here. I have a .txt file containing the filenames for files of interest. I want to walk a directory and subdirectories and if a file matches one of the filenames in the list, then it is to be copied to a destination.

```
files_to_find = []
with open('outliers.txt', 'r') as f:
    files_to_find = [line.strip() for line in f]

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if file in files_to_find:
                fileSrc = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(subdir), file)
                shutil.copyfile(fileSrc, os.path.join('C:/blah/blah/dest', file))
```

But this doesn't manage to match the filenames with the elements of the list (they are there) - what am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: looks OK. Can you print `file` and `files_to_find` to see if there's a big mistake somewhere (absolute path, casing issue). Casing issue is likely.

Comment: Step 1 of debugging: `print(files_to_find)`. Debugging complete.

Comment: Yep, I can print the files_to_find and it looks fine. Next step? :/

Comment: Try `print(file, files_to_find)` to check what you are trying to compare

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, so the problem has to be the contents of your file. I expect it's either a casing issue or you forgot to include the file extension in the file names.

Comment: `if file in files_to_find` performs an exact inclusion match, not a substring match. Common mistake. either that or casing